# Take parameters from fastlane argument

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-gym

Fastlane file look like this

```
lane :build do |options|
  scheme = options[:scheme]
  puts scheme
end
```

But the output of `puts` is **coming blank** whenever I pass any value in it.
I am calling the fast lane like this from terminal :- `fastlane build options:Release`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example above, you would need to run:
`fastlane build scheme:Release` to output `Release` as you're expecting.

`options` is the dictionary of arguments, and `:scheme` keys for the argument provided after `scheme` in the command.